# Handling date time dependent data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Currently I'm developing a Node.js application that will run inside a Raspberry.

The application fetches posts data from an API, where each post has it's own start/end date and times.

I need to know when the start/end time is reached so I can run some code. How could I handle that on Node.js? Right now, I created a service with `setInterval()` that **runs every 10 seconds for each post**, and checks if it should run the code or not. However, I was wondering if there are any other solutions for this problem.

Is the solution I currently have bad? Or CPU intensive/memory intensive?

Comment: A naive first improvement would be to `setInterval` to the difference between the start/end date and now. The next improvement could be to `setInterval` to the difference between the next start/end date of all posts and now. How many posts are we talking about? Will your app keep them in memory or stored on disk?

Comment: Could you explain why the ```setInterval()``` "scheduling" would be better? Wouldn't it use more memory, since the intervals and callbacks would stay in memory? The amount of posts is not set yet, but the max would be the max storage of the Raspberry. Post data will be stored in a NeDB file database, so if the app gets offline, it'll still be able to run with local data. Since this is my first app, I don't have performance metrics to compare against, and wouldn't be able to say if something could have bad performance.

Comment: The first improvement reduces the iterations for each post as it will not be called every 10s, but only once - when it is needed. (You might think about whether the due dates can change.) With the second improvement you only have one `setInterval` running are basically putting the app to sleep till the next post is due.

Comment: If you are having a large number of posts, it's quite inefficient to run a `setInterval` for each and every post.

I would differentiate two tasks:
1. Retrieve the posts incl. due dates and put them in the database. Update them if needed. That job would run periodically.

2. Similarly there is another job, that asks the DB if there are posts due and then performs the necessary operation on it. This job runs every `n` seconds. If your operation is long-running and there might be more than one post due within that time, you can think about running more than one instance of this job.